# Is there a way to listen db updates?

Tags: vuefire

I'm using vuexfire for my project at the moment. I can get data ready state within then block. See below code.

```
actions: {
    loadLeads: firestoreAction(({ state, commit, bindFirestoreRef }) => {
      if (state.dataInitialised) return true;
      // return the promise returned by `bindFirestoreRef`
      bindFirestoreRef("labels", collection("labels").doc("leads"));
      return bindFirestoreRef("leads", collection("leads"), {
        reset: false
      }).then(() => {
        commit("dataInitialised");
      });
    })
  },
```

But, is there an easy way to get notified when doc created, modified?

Many Thanks.